# JSON is overwriting the old data how to keep on adding data with new ID

Tags: php, json

so, I am working on a JSON file that should keep on incrementing IDs. 
However I get stuck at id:0 and when I insert new data the old data will be replaced by the new one (it keeps id:0).

I am not entirely sure what code is related and what not, so I will post whatever I think should be related and if someone with more knowledge related to JSON could adjust (in case it needs any) it, I would appreciate it a lot.

The include database_json.php contains the following code:

```
$databaseFile = file_get_contents('json_files/database.json');
$databaseJson = json_decode($databaseFile, true);
$database = $databaseJson['data'];

// below starts a new page, the page that submits the form called saveJson.php
include_once('database_json.php');

$data = $_POST;
//Setup an empty array.
$errors = array();
if (isset($data)) {
    $newExerciseData = $data;
    $exerciseArray = $data['main_object'];
    $databaseFile = 'json_files/database.json';
    $textContent = file_get_contents($databaseFile);
    $database = json_decode($textContent, true);

    if ($data['id'] === 'new') {
        if (count($database['data']) == 0) {
            $ID = 0;
        } else {
            $maxID = max($database['data']);
            $ID = ++$maxID["id"];
        }

        $newJsonFile = 'jsonData_' . $ID . '.json';
        $newJsonFilePath = 'json_files/' . $newJsonFile;
        //Create new database exercise_txt
        $newArrayData = array(
            'id' => $ID,
            // a lot of variables that aren't related to the problem
        );
        $database['data'][] = $newArrayData;
        file_put_contents($databaseFile, json_encode($database, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        file_put_contents($newJsonFilePath, json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    } else {
        $index = array_search((int) $_POST['id'], array_column($database['data'], 'id'));
        $correctJsonFile = 'json_files/jsonData_' . $_POST['id'] . '.json';
        $newJsonFile = 'jsonData_' . $_POST['id'] . '.json';
        $newJsonFilePath = 'json_files/' . $newJsonFile;
        //Create new database exercise_txt
        $newArrayData2 = array(
            'id' => (int) $_POST['id'],
            // more not related to problem variables
        );
        $database['data'][$index] = $newArrayData2;
        file_put_contents($databaseFile, json_encode($database, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
        file_put_contents($newJsonFilePath, json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    }
    echo json_encode($newExerciseData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

EDIT: someone wanted me to post how the JSON itself looked like... so this is how it looks:
The file is called: database.json

```
{
    "data":
        [
            {
                "id":0,
                "exercisetitle":"Test300520180924",
                "exerciseWord":["huiswerk"],
                "syllables":["Huis","werk"],
                "file":"jsonData_.json",
                "audio":null,"language":null
            }
        ]
}
```

(do not mind the audio and language, that's something for later on.

The best I could do was this, yes I read the stuff about making a post and how to properly format stuff etc. but I people would often say I need to include certain code etc etc. and it mostly would turn out messy as hell, so I would rather have a bit too much code (the code I think is related) then not have enough.

Cheers!

Comment: This is probably something you want to be careful about `count($database['data']) == 0`, you'll want to use `===` instead since 
[it might return 0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: It does return 0, because that's an ID aswell. It starts off with 0 and goes up. but thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: I suspect your problem is with the call to `max`. Unless `id` is the first element in the `$database['data']` arrays, it won't sort on that element. What happens if you try `$maxID = max(array_column($database['data'], 'id')); $ID = ++$maxID;`?

Comment: Still keeps the ID on 0. id is the first element in $database['data']

Comment: Its not recommended to use JSON as database, because without locking mechanism two people will eventually be writing the file at the same time, which can lead to bad JSON or overwriting data.
You better off using SQLite as database.
JSON is good for configuration files, logs and data streaming.

Comment: A very honest answer from my side? I don't care. We were told to use JSON instead of SQL and we weren't allowed to use SQL. No idea why, but since they want me to use JSON to store data i'll do so. What happens after that isn't my job... is it?

Comment: Probably going to have to provide more information/format it better. i.e. example of the json. Also you said this code is from the `database_json.php`, but within that you have an include to that exact same file? You do also have an extra closing `}` at the end.. but I'm not sure if that's because you've only got a sub-sect of the code?

Comment: @Mikey I commented underneath the 3 lines of code that the file that was including the database_json.php was a new file called saveJson.php